# Why my Docker Certboot container stopped? Exit status 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./proxy/logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl
  certbot:
    image: docker.io/certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt
```

After the restart

```
      Name                     Command               State                                    Ports                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ingress_certbot_1   certbot                          Exit 1                                                                         
ingress_proxy_1     /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,:::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
```

This what showed on screen

```
certbot_1  | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot_1  | Certbot doesn't know how to automatically configure the web server on this system.
```

This is the output of the tree command

```
.
├── certbot
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── accounts [error opening dir]
│   │   ├── archive [error opening dir]
│   │   ├── csr
│   │   │   ├── 0000_csr-certbot.pem
│   │   │   └── 0001_csr-certbot.pem
│   │   ├── keys [error opening dir]
│   │   ├── live [error opening dir]
│   │   ├── renewal
│   │   │   └── example.conf
│   │   └── renewal-hooks
│   │       ├── deploy
│   │       ├── post
│   │       └── pre
│   └── www
├── docker-compose.yml
├── proxy
│   └── logs
│       ├── access.log
│       └── error.log
└── sites-enabled
    ├── http_2_https.conf
    └── my-dev.conf
```

It seems that something wrong with path trajectory,regarding volume mounts.

How to find out what went wrong?